# Proving that Retarded K-G Propagator is Green function (Peskin & Schroeder 2.56)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

I am trying to derive Peskin & Schroeders expression $2.56$:
$$(\partial^2 +m^2)D_R(x-y)=-i\delta^{(4)}(x-y)\tag{2.56}$$
with $$D_R(x-y)=\theta(x^0-y^0)\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle.\tag{2.55}$$
Following the answer provided [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/710616/) I was able to get through most of the derivation, but  have trouble understanding some of the minor details. The first step is evidently to apply the K-G operator as $\partial^2=\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}$ and using the product rule:
$$=\partial_\mu ((\partial^\mu\theta(x^0-y^0))\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle+\theta(x^0-y^0)\partial^{\mu}\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle+m^2\theta(x^0-y^0))\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle$$
$$=\partial^2\theta(x^0-y^0))\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle+(\partial^\mu\theta(x^0-y^0)\partial_\mu\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle +m^2\theta(x^0-y^0))\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle+\partial_\mu\theta(x^0-y^0)\partial^{\mu}\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle+\theta(x^0-y^0)\partial^{2}\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle$$

Here, the mass term cancels out with the $\partial^2$ term because it satisfies K-G on $\phi(x)$. My problem is with the "cross terms". There, we have

$$\partial_\mu \theta(x^0-y^0)=\partial^\mu\theta(x^0-y^0)=\partial_t\theta(x^0-y^0)$$
So it is evident that those parts are equivalent. My question is this: How is this sastisfied:
$$\partial_\mu\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle=\partial^\mu\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle$$
I know that the time derivatives give $\partial_t \phi(x)=\Pi(x)$, but I believe that there should be a minus sign difference between the two spatial derivatives, which evidently is not the case. Why is that?

Comment: "but I belive that there should be a minus sign difference between the two spatial derivatives" What spatial derivatives? Your cross term can't have spatial derivatives because $\vec\nabla\theta(x^0 - y^0)=0$, only the time derivatives are in the cross term...

Comment: @hft I meant the term $\partial_\mu\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle$ . But I think I finally got it. Since $\partial_\mu=(\partial_t, \partial_i)$ and $\partial^\mu=(\partial_t, -\partial_i)$ After multiplying we get: $\partial_\i$\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle+\partial^\i$\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle$. thus only the time part survives and they add up to 2.